# Fortran: array size known at compilation time VS array size known at execution time

Tags: arrays, fortran

This question kind of follows [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214014/fortran-dynamic-arrays-vs-automatic-array-avoiding-memory-allocation).

Suppose you have a subroutine `foo` that will be called several thousands of times in your program. This subroutine makes use of several small local arrays, which values does not need to be stored over successive calls. The subroutine looks like this :

```
SUBROUTINE foo(globalArray)

USE MYMODULE 

REAL, DIMENSION(:)           :: globalArray

REAL, DIMENSION(myDimension) :: localArray1, localArray2, localArray3

...
Do computations with globalArray and localArray*
...

END SUBROUTINE
```

The size myDimension is computed at execution time, in a pre-processing routine, and is stored in module `MYMODULE`. It is always pretty small (between 4 and 35). I have more than three local arrays (typically 15-20). Additionally, I should say that the call to this routine represents 95% of the execution time of my code.

I noticed a few things that are pretty similar to the link above. For the exact same (small) case and same (short) computation (but replicable in bigger, longer), on same machine with same compiler :

- (1) If `myDimension` is indeed determined at execution time, walltime for my whole program is 2.13 seconds;
- (2) If I replace `myDimension` above with an explicit value (say 4), walltime for my whole program is 1.31 seconds;
- (3) If I replace local arrays with allocatable arrays (stored in MYMODULE for example), that I allocate them in a pre-processing step, use them in my subroutine and deallocate them in a post-processing step, then walltime for my whole program is 2.57 seconds.

Then here are my questions:

- How is memory differently handled between cases (1) and (2) ? Do the localArray* go on the stack in case (2), while they go on the heap in case (1) ?
- Is there a way to avoid the low performance due to size known at execution time ?

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: You should show the code to see what you are doing with themm As small example as possible, but MCVE (C..complete V..verifiable)

Comment: There was a similar question aske very recently.(IIRC this month), you should try to search. There is no stack in sight, more likely static storage. Remember compilers of FORTRAN 77 can be done to gnerate code without any stack at all.

Comment: How things are implemented depends very much on the implementation in use (platform/compiler/compiler version/compiler options), none of which have been specified.  The significance of how things are implemented depends very much on what happens in "Do computations...".  Does myDimension vary each time that the subroutine is called, or after pre-processing does it have the same value across all calls to the subroutine?

Comment: You are exactly right @IanH, sorry for that mistake. This was observed both on latest gnu and intel compilers, both of them on OsX and CentOs platforms, with `-O3` option in both cases. The value of `myDimension` is computed once in a pre-processing step and is stored in module `MYMODULE`, that is used in this subroutine. So it has the same value across all calls to subroutine `foo`