# Why does Fortran spend so much time on 'for_allocate' or 'for_deallocate'?

Tags: optimization, fortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to optimise some Fortran code that I have inherited. It is a very repetitive code that takes days to run and I am trying hard to reduce the run time. After reducing the run time of some of the functions and subroutines the latest bottleneck, according to VTune Amplifier, is for_deallocation and for_allocation, specifically called from one subroutine. I am slightly unsure as to what the 'for_' means in front of allocation and deallocation, especially as no allocations are made in the routine. A summary of the code is as follows:

```
module global_variables
    double precision, allocatable :: input_values(:)
    double precision, allocatable :: input_values2(:,:)
    double precision, allocatable :: indices_array(:)
    double precision, allocatable :: value_array(:)
    double precision, allocatable :: final_result(:)
end module

subroutine func1()
    allocate( ...global values...)
    do I=1,n
        call func2(I)
    end do

end subroutine func1

subroutine func2(I)
    double precision, intent(in) :: I
    double precision :: value, x
    double precision, dimension(3) :: output_array

    call find_Indices(x)
    value_array = input_values(indices_array)
    call calculations(value)

    do j = 1,3
        value_array = input_values2(indices_array,j)
        call calculations(output_array(j))
    end do

    final_result = output_array * value

end subroutine func2

subroutine find_Indices(position)
    indices_array = some calculation on position
end subroutine find_Indices

subroutine calculations(output)
    double precision :: output
    output = some calculation on value_array
end subroutine calculations
```

I have had to summarise rather than paste the actual code because of its nature. The subroutine with the excessive allocation/deallocation time is func2. There are no allocation statements in the subroutine and there are no reallocations of the global values. Using the documentation available to me I have been unable to ascertain what is meant by 'for_' in front of allocate/deallocate or as to why so much time is spent on it in func2. Because of the size of the code I specified placing all arrays on the heap, which would account for an allocate, however allowing arrays back on the stack has not reduced the time at all.

Is anyone able to help me understand the nature of for_allocate/for_deallocate? Or the reason why this function would spend so much time calling it?

SOLUTION:

While googling array properties, for another issue I was having, I came across this post:
[Fortran: dynamic arrays vs. automatic array Avoiding Memory Allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214014/fortran-dynamic-arrays-vs-automatic-array-avoiding-memory-allocation)

Which shows that there is significant overhead with modifying allocatable global arrays. Changing value_array from an allocatable array to a pointer array (double precicsion, pointer :: value_array(:)) has removed the majority of the overhead from for_allocate and for_deallocate and reduced the runtime to 1/5th of what it was. This suggests to me that when the values of an allocatable array are modified, the original array is deallocated and a new one is allocated. This may be well known in the Fortran community, but as a new user, that has not come across any form of documentation of this behaviour, it was not obvious to me.

Comment: We need some context.  A compilable subroutine, at least (better would be a small program), and the compiler you are using.

Comment: In the absence of better information, one might guess that you need in-lining or such optimizations to preserve the dynamic arrays across multiple calls to func2, as well as possibly trying stack vs. heap. output_array seems most likely to be moved to heap with costly allocation.  for_ simply refers to Fortran runtime library.

Comment: I am using the intel 17.0 compiler. I shall see what I can do about creating a compilable example.
I should have realised that 'for_' would stand for Fortran, I just got the impression that Intel used 'fort' as the abbreviation for Fortran.

Comment: Please prepare a fully compilable example ([mcve]), not just a code summary.

Comment: Ok I shall remember that next time I post a question.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: For ifort, the option -heap-arrays is often recommended, but that could be a cause of excessive library allocation calls in this context.

Comment: The link you show does not say anything about allocatable vs. pointer. Pointer arrays are heap arrays in the same way as pointer arrays. The differences are somewhere else.

Comment: *"This suggests to me that when the values of an allocatable array are modified, the original array is deallocated and a new one is allocated.*" Complete utter nonsense.

Comment: No the link did not, but it did show that using allocatable arrays globally to pass values to other subroutines can increase overheads, through increased calls to allocate and deallocate. This suggests that using a pointer, which points to a specific memory register, should prevent data from being deallocated and allocated to other places in the memory. Going back through the code and the VTune Amplifier results, I found that the amount of time spent in allocate/ deallocate in each subroutine was proportional to the amount of calls to the subroutine and modifications made to value_array.

Comment: As for the next comment... I have made it clear I am new to Fortran, if you wish to call the process by which I came to a hypothesis, or the hypothesis itself, nonsense then please explain. I want to learn how to use Fortran effectively and would like to understand this behaviour as it has repercussions in other parts of the code, and any other coding I do with Fortran. So I would be grateful if you could actually explain what happens. That would also allow the question to be marked with an answer.

Comment: I'm wondering whether in these lines `value_array = input_values(indices_array)` and `value_array = input_values2(indices_array,j)`, does `indices_array` change its size depending on the action of `find_Indices(x)`? (because the latter function defines `indices_array`). If so, does "automatic reallocation" occur for `value_array` etc every time `func2()` is called?

Comment: That would make sense, and was something I thought about. However find_Indices only ever returns the same number of indices. And just to make sure, indices_array, value_array and the assignment loops in find_Indices are defined, size wise, by a constant integer in global_variables. Secondly VTunes Amplifier also gives the amount of time spent in 'for_reallocate', so it is definitely deallocating and allocating. It is a bit of a conundrum.

Comment: @MartinD I would like to explain the details, but I don't have a crystal ball. Without the [mcve] I could only guess what might be happening in the code you don't show.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the examples in "6. Indirect Array Access" at https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fortran-array-data-and-arguments-and-vectorization

The repeated allocations are (very probably) because when using an index array, the compiler allocates a temporary array (example 7.1 in the link above) to store the resulting array. The alternative is to loop explicitly over the indices (example 7.2).

The link above is for MIC architectures but the principle is likely the same on a regular CPU. The thread here https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/685221 also hints at the creation of temporary arrays for array indexing.

To be certain of what is going on, there is the possibility to inspect assembly output or to test explicitly the "explicit indexing" scenario.